# Simplify jQuery conditions that contains different input boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-confirm

### Explanation

Each table's row contains a delete icon at the last column. The icons are wrapped with anchor tag with respective database id. The user will click on the icon to delete that particular row (some IDs are not meant to be deleted example system admin).

There is a scenario where user able to manually change the id from the Developer's tool. So upon user click on the icon, the function `fn_deleteRow` is triggered and ajax `GetDelUser` was called. If the user is authorized to delete, the dialog should display buttons `Yes/No`, else the dialog should display warning message with button `Ok` only.

### My question

If the user is not authorized to delete certain IDs, upon database validation, the dialog button should just display Ok instead of Yes/No. How do I make it dynamic using the code below?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function fn_deleteRow(id) {
    $.confirm({
      backgroundDismiss: true,
      icon: 'fa fa-exclamation',
      theme: 'modern',
      closeIcon: true,
      animation: 'scale',
      type: 'red',
      content: function() {
        var self = this;
        return $.ajax({
          url: 'action/<?php echo basename(__FILE__);?>',
          dataType: 'json',
          data: 'GetDelUser&id=' + id,
          method: 'post'
        }).done(function(data) {
          console.log(data);
          if (data.status == 'success') {
            self.setContentAppend('<h3>' + data.name + '</h3>');
          } else {
            self.setContentAppend('<div>' + data.message + '</div>');
          }
        }).fail(function() {
          self.setContentAppend('<div>Fail!</div>');
        }).always(function() {
          //self.setContentAppend('<div>Always!</div>');
        })
      },
      contentLoaded: function(data, status, xhr) {
        //this.setContentAppend('<div>Content loaded!</div>');
      },
      onContentReady: function() {
        //this.setContentAppend('<div>Content ready!</div>');
      },
      title: 'Confirm to delete:',
      buttons: {
        'Yes': {
          btnClass: 'btn-red',
          action: function() {
            var self = this;
            self.setContent('Checking callback flow');
            return $.ajax({
              url: 'action/<?php echo basename(__FILE__);?>',
              dataType: 'json',
              data: 'ConfirmDelete&id=' + id,
              method: 'post'
            }).done(function(data) {
              console.log(data);
              self.setContentAppend('<div>Done!</div>');
              $.notify({
                message: data.message
              }, {
                type: data.status,
                placement: {
                  from: "top",
                  align: "left"
                },
                newest_on_top: true,
                delay: 0
              });
              if (data.status == 'success') {
                $('#userTable').DataTable()
                  .row(row.parents('tr'))
                  .remove()
                  .draw();
              }
            }).fail(function() {
              self.setContentAppend('<div>Fail!</div>');
            }).always(function() {
              self.setContentAppend('<div>Always!</div>');
            });
          }
        },
        /*cancel: function () {
          $.alert('Canceled!');
        },*/
        'No': {
          btnClass: 'btn-blue'
        }
      }
    });
  }

  $(document).on("click", ".btnDelete", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var row = $(this);
    var id = row.attr('id');
    console.log(id);

    fn_deleteRow(id);
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.2/jquery-confirm.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.2/jquery-confirm.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="table-responsive">
  <table id="userTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Created Date</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><a href="user-master-detail.php?id=3">Jeff</a></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Active</td>
        <td>2017-11-10 00:00:00</td>
        <td><a href="" class="btnDelete" id="3"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><a href="user-master-detail.php?id=2">Wong Ching Chong</a></td>
        <td>myemail@domain.com</td>
        <td>0123456789</td>
        <td>Active</td>
        <td>2017-05-10 12:20:19</td>
        <td><a href="" class="btnDelete" id="2"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><a href="user-master-detail.php?id=1">System Administrator</a></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>0198765432</td>
        <td>Active</td>
        <td>2017-03-29 20:34:51</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: you are using the confirm dialog to call the ajax for the deletion and confirm button will always have both `ok` and `cancel` buttons, if i am understanding correctly you don't want a confirm dialog when user is not authorized in that case you need to wrap your confirm inside `if(){} else{}` of your ajax `success` / `done`  function  and display a `confirm` or `alert` dialog based on the response received.

Comment: I get what u mean. So there will be two separate $.confirm, one is the Ok button another one is Yes/No buttons right?

Comment: yes there should be $.confirm for allowed and $.alert for not allowed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `$.alert` in case not alllowed and `$.confirm` in case allowed and move them inside the ajax `success` function rather than having call `$.confirm` by default and sending ajax call.